# How can I add a Corporate / Exchange account if there is no option in the "Accounts & Sync" list

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, exchange, accounts

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.2.

If I go to Settings, Accounts & sync, ADD ACCOUNT, there is no "Corporate" or "Exchange" options at all. I only have Facebook, Google, Twitter, and Dropbox. I haven't rooted my phone or made any modifications beyond installing apps from the Play store.

Under Settings, Apps, ALL, I have something listed called "Exchange Services" but it says that it is using 0.00B storage, cache, etc.

Any help on adding an exchange account to my phone would be appreciated. I've been using it with just my Google account for quite a while but would like to add a corporate exchange account for work.

Comment: Is there an "Email" app in the drawer or an "Email" option on the Add Account list?

Comment: Like @Chahk said. I added mine by entering the details in the email app.

Comment: I have the same issue on my Droid Bionic (4.0.4); I'm trying to determine if I may have disabled an app that is required for this functionality, but none of my disabled apps appear relevant.

Comment: Update: I had disabled the email app after upgrading to ICS.    Re-enabling it made the option reappear in the accounts setting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add it from the email app itself?

Go into the app and and select the "manual setup" option, and then you will be able to add a Pop3, IMAP, or Exchange account.

Answer (score 0):

K9 mail may have an option to connect to your account. See https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/K9MailAndExchange